# What is java Object equivalent in Protocol Buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers

I want to serialize the following DTO using Protocol Buffer . Can somebody let me know what would be the .proto file entry for java  Object type.

```
public class Person  {
    private Object role;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A `bytes`, that is a [`ByteString`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString) in Java, and a ByteString can be easily converted to a `byte[]` or an `InputStream` which you can e.g. warp in an [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) and therefore read your serialized `Object` from it.

It's not very hard, but also not very protobuf-ish and/or a wise thing to do. I suggest saving some logical representation of your `role` object into the protobuf instead. I'm sure there is a solid option for you somewhere - be it a String, or an enum or something, you should save some the logical state of your role instead of the actual serialized object, and then try to construct the object upon retrieval.